# Google sheets httpresponse script returning a blank response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the http response function on google sheets using apps script

```
function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
var response_code ;
try {
response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
}
catch( error ) {
response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
}
finally {
return response_code ;
}
}
```

Then calling the function of httpresponse(cell) in google sheets. The problem is for some cells its showing the response as 200,404 etc ... however for some the result is showing blank however the url is working and reachable?

Comment: can you provide a uri for which the answer is empty?

Answer (score 0):

If the [`String.match` fails, `null` is returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). This returns a blank cell. Instead of `try...catch`, set [`muteHttpExceptions`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en#fetchurl,-params) to `true`:

```
const getResponseCode = (url) =>
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getResponseCode();
```